# Compare enum with NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, comparison, nsnumber

I am doing some drawing and have a class named `Draw2DHelper` that defines an `enum` of constants for the types of drawings I'm making, and a property `drawingType` that uses the types:

```
enum {
    LINE_DRAWING,
    BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING,
    FRACTAL_DRAWING,
    POINT_DRAWING
};
typedef NSNumber * drawingTypes;


@property drawingTypes drawingType;
```

in a previous scene I'm defining a UIPickerView to reflect my drawing types, and populating the array that is bound to it with this code (which is why i'm using NSNumber) : 
I've now traced the problem to something about the picker and the way it's returning the data. I have the following code in my parent ViewController:

```
NSNumber *myNum1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING];
NSNumber *myNum2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:LINE_DRAWING];
NSNumber *myNum3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:POINT_DRAWING];
NSNumber *myNum4 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:FRACTAL_DRAWING];


_nameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Bezier Path", @"Line Drawing", @"Point Drawing", @"Fractal Drawing", nil];

_typeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: myNum1, myNum2, myNum3, myNum4,nil];
```

so later, in the pickerView didSelectRow method I have this:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0)
    {
        _drawingType = [_typeArray objectAtIndex: row];
        NSString *drawingTypeName = [ _nameArray objectAtIndex:row ] ;
    }
}
```

something funky is happening when _drawingType gets assigned; I'm not sure I have the pointers correct there... I am using strings to populate the visuals of the picker - should I just use those to make the comparison easier? What am I doing wrong? 
I'm thinking I may not have bound the array correctly to the picker so the didSelectRow method isn't returning the right data. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Object types aren't usually... typedef'd.  Perhaps you meant to typedef NSUInteger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drawing type needs to be int value. Not an Object(NSNumber).

The code should be written as below.

```
typedef enum {
    LINE_DRAWING,
    BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING,
    FRACTAL_DRAWING,
    POINT_DRAWING
} DrawingType;


@property(nonatomic) DrawingType drawingType;


- (void) createDrawing: (DrawingType) type : (UIBezierPath*) path :(int) maxPoints
{
   switch (type)    
   {
    case POINT_DRAWING:
   // do something
       break;
    case BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING:
   // do something
       break;
   default:
      [self drawRandomSetOfSquaredBezierPaths: (UIBezierPath*) path :(int) maxPoints];
      break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

dont see any reason, why it has to be NSNumber objects, just use integers

```
enum {
    LINE_DRAWING,
    BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING,
    FRACTAL_DRAWING,
    POINT_DRAWING
};
typedef NSInteger drawingTypes;



switch (self.drawingType) //is this inside -create…? that uses type instead   
{
    case POINT_DRAWING:
   // do something
       break;
    case BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING:
   // do something
       break;
   default:
      [self drawRandomSetOfSquaredBezierPaths: (UIBezierPath*) path :(int) maxPoints];
      break;
}
```

typedefed enums is a C technique, objects live in the Objective-C layer. They don't fit togther very well.

also having a look on`- (void) createDrawing: (drawingTypes) type : (UIBezierPath*) path :(int) maxPoints` I have to believe, that you meant to pass a bitmask like `(LINE_DRAWING| BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING)` for parameter `type`. you can do that only with C integers.

Answer (score 4):

I think @vikingosegundo's answer is the way to go, but just to answer the original question:

If you define your enum like this:

```
enum {
    LINE_DRAWING,
    BEZIER_PATH_DRAWING,
    FRACTAL_DRAWING,
    POINT_DRAWING
};
typedef NSNumber * drawingTypes;
```

you can then compare NSNumber objects with the enum using [Objective-C literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

```
NSNumber *number = (wherever your number comes from)
if ([number isEqualToNumber:@(LINE_DRAWING)]) {
}
```

which is the same as `[number isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:LINE_DRAWIN]])`

Comment: thank you for all the commentary - turns out that all I needed to do was convert my enum to a regular int type - all worked out well after that.

Comment: @marina if one of the answers solved your problem, please accept the answer. See the [About Page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.